# Passing a flask session variable to a different view returns type None

Tags: javascript, python, json, session, flask

I am trying to pass a session variable that is set on the login view, to another view. However, the session variable always returns None if a form is submitted, I want the session variable to retain.

The tools page has some form fields, and one text box that handles autocomplete search based off of the session['foo'] which is sent on good login.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get some form variables here
        if login is valid:
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            session['foo'] = utils.get_data()
            return redirect(url_for('tools'))
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/tools", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def tools():
    if session['foo'] is None:
        print "Data is None type, getting data"
        session['foo'] = utils.get_data()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Handling some forms here
        # If one of these forms are submitted, session['foo'] is set to None :(

    return render_template('tools.html', foo_data=session['foo'])
```

Utils.py

```
def get_data():
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)  # FYI, server won't allow GET for this call.
    # Do json type stuff here to make response.content nice for javascript
   return response
```

Essentially, what happens with this code is, every time I submit a form, I have to check if it's None and invoke utils.get_data(), I want the data returned by this method to retain for the entire length of the session.

EDIT:
Solution, session variable object is too big. Some ways to solve this could include;

- Use AJAX to avoid refresh the page each submission, thus not flushing the session object
- Split the object into smaller chunks
- Avoid storing large objects in cookies- use local storage

Comment: did you set a secret key, as explained [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions)?

Comment: I most certainly do :) I can use the variable just fine on the javascript/client side, my issue is with it becoming None every time a form refreshes the page.

EDIT: Actually mine is set as app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'

Comment: Is "session['search_data'] = utils.get_data() " a copy paste error or should that also be "session['foo'] = utils.get_data()"

Comment: Copy and paste error, will fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of the data being put into session. And if it is too large try using a smaller object.

From the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions)

> A note on cookie-based sessions: Flask will take the values you put into the session object and serialize them into a cookie. If you are finding some values do not persist across requests, cookies are indeed enabled, and you are not getting a clear error message, check the size of the cookie in your page responses compared to the size supported by web browsers.

Original post:

> Technically the utils.get_data method is a separate session than the web call. What is the get data method trying to achieve?

Comment: get_data() simply requests a json dictionary from an endpoint with python requests. I manipulate the dict into a list e.g. ["foo", "bar", "stringz"]

tools() sends the data to the html page, where javascript handles the autocomplete using the list as the data.

Comment: What is the size of the data being requested? From the doco "A note on cookie-based sessions: Flask will take the values you put into the session object and serialize them into a cookie. If you are finding some values do not persist across requests, cookies are indeed enabled, and you are not getting a clear error message, check the size of the cookie in your page responses compared to the size supported by web browsers."

Comment: Additionally is the endpoint controlled by this flask app or hosted externally?

Comment: Jase, it looks like it is the size. Thank-you, I didn't even consider this. The end point is controlled externally, it is a very large object, if I return something smaller it works fine.

Make this an answer :)!

Comment: I have updated my question to include your solution as well as other possible work-arounds. Thanks, Jase.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a server-side session if the data size is the problem.
It is possible to store Flask sessions inside your database and just store the session id in the cookie.

For example this [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/110/) shows how to store your session data in MongoDB.